# Magento 2: Creating a custom indexer for my own module

Tags: magento2, indexing, elasticsearch

I am new to Magento. I have a custom module in Magento 2 that has a table with data and CRUD models. I want to create an indexer for it to be able to push it to Elasticsearch.

I already created the indexer.xml and mview.xml files, as well as class inside the `Model\Indexer` namespace. Here it is:

```
namespace VendorName\Faq\Model\Indexer;

class Question implements \Magento\Framework\Indexer\ActionInterface, \Magento\Framework\Mview\ActionInterface
{
  public function execute($ids) {
    // ???
  }

  public function executeFull() {
    // ???
  }

  public function executeList(array $ids) {
    // ???
  }

  public function executeRow($id0 {
    // ???
  }
}
```

The official documentation has nothing to tell about how to get data for indexing - it only has a structure for the Indexer class.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, Index is a data structure that helps to improve the performance of data searches and queries on a table.

**Steps to create custom index**

https://dolphinwebsolution.com/how-to-create-custom-indexer-in-magento-2/